# Поиск данных List

Tags: c#, wpf, list, поиск

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Я разрабатываю приложения по учету книг в книжном магазине. Я пытался перебирать разные варианты поиска, но все выходило так себе. Если пользователь вводит только автора, то необходимо искать по автору, если вводит автора и название книги, то ищет по автору и названию книги соответственно и т.д. Данные книги хранятся в классе Book. Имеется список из данных книг.

```
private List<Book> _books = new List<Book>();

        _books.Add(new Book("Дарси Эмма", "Ловушка для босса", "0-2736-1163-1", "85.12 Д78", Genres.роман, "2007", 300));
        _books.Add(new Book("Юлия Федотова", "Свет. Испытание Добром?", "0-3861-0094-2", "85.13 Ф68", Genres.фэнтези, "2012", 340));
        _books.Add(new Book("Виктор Точинов", "Дураки умирают первыми", "0-5021-9401-4", "85.14 Т77", Genres.фэнтези, "2015", 320));
        _books.Add(new Book("Агата Кристи", "Вилла «Белый Конь»", "0-5675-7425-3", "85.15 К69", Genres.детектив, "1961", 420));
```

Данные я беру из формы вот таким путем

```
        string author = AuthorBook_TextBox.Text.ToLower();
        string title = TitleBook_TextBox.Text.ToLower();
        string code = CodeBook_TextBox.Text.ToLower();
        string cipher = CipherBook_TextBox.Text.ToLower();
        Genres genre = (Genres)GenreBook_ComboBox.SelectedIndex;
        int price=0;
        if(PriceBook_TextBox.Text.Length!=0)
        {
            try
            {
                price = int.Parse(PriceBook_TextBox.Text);
            }
            catch
            {
                PriceBook_TextBox.Foreground = Brushes.Red;
                PriceBook_TextBox.ToolTip = "Это поле введено не коректно!";
            }
        }
```

По сути надо работать со списком _books, но как лучше искать по отдельным кускам я не знаю. Буду рад помощи.

Comment: Что за "отдельные куски"?

Comment: если я ввожу только автора, то искать только по автору , год, шифр и т.п. не учитывать при поиске

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну что-то такое будет:

```
var books_selected = _books.Where(x =>
    (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(author) || x.Author.ToLower().Contains(author)) &&
    (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(title)  || x.Title.ToLower().Contains(title)) &&
    ...
    )
```

Только класс `Book` вы не показали, поэтому я наугад пишу названия его полей.

А цену обычно для поиска задают в виде диапазона (нижней и верхней границы), точную цену никогда не ищут.

Comment: Сейчас попробую

Comment: Спасибо большое. Попробовал вашу реализацию, вроде все работает нормально.

Comment: @Григорий Надеюсь, с `genre` и `price` вы уже сами разберётесь, как их в выборку добавить, если нет - спрашивайте. Текстовые то поля все аналогично будут, а с другими типами немного подумать может придётся.

Comment: постараюсь что-нибудь придумать. Спасибо еще раз, очень сильно выручили.